# How to make report viewer control to export in xls format instead of xlsx?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Our application needs to be able to generate .xls format from the report viewer control. However, when I try to export to Excel, it only gives me two options (.xlsx and Other files).

In order to generate as .xls, we need to use 'Other files' option and set to .xls but this will result in mismatch of file format and extension and the user will always obtain a [warning dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzuyS.png)  when trying to open that file. I suspect it was just renaming the file to .xls but its format is still .xlsx.

Is it possible to set the default export format of Excel type files to `.xls` for the Report Viewer control?

[image]

**Figure 1: Report viewer shows 3 types of files to export in**

[image]

**Figure 2: Report viewer defaults to .xlsx format when choosing a file. Would prefer it to default to .xls format instead**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Handle report export event
2. Use ReportViewer's ExportDialog() method and use `ListRenderingExtensions()` method to see the list of extensions
   available
3. Set `e.Cancel = true` to prevent a repeat of this event

**Code:**

```
    private void reportViewerControl_ReportExport(object sender, ReportExportEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Extension.LocalizedName.ToUpper().Equals("EXCEL"))
        {
            reportViewerControl.ExportDialog(reportViewerControl.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()[0]);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```